# ng-route $state in service

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to migrate ng-route to ui-router, and I'm, facing an issue regarding usage a $state in my custom service.

Is there some workaround to get access to the relevant for ui-router $route and $routeParams?

From there I need to access:

```
    $route.routes
    $route.current
    $route.current.$$route.keys
    $routeParams
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? (If you're getting error-msg, it could help to see that error...)

Comment: When I try to get $state, it tells me:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $state is not defined

Comment: post some of your code so we can have a look ;)

Comment: One of the functions that I have a problem to migrate is: 

`
   function _getRoute(id) {
    for (var p in $route.routes) {
     if ($route.routes.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      if ($route.routes[p].id === id) {
       return $route.routes[p];
      }
     }
    }
   }
`

My service starts like this:
`
 .service('routeGenerator', [
  '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($state, $stateParams) {
   'use strict';
`